# Rendering Math Formulas

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

What would be the best approach to implement math formula rendering in a Cocoa application?

There is a utility app included with MacOS X called *Grapher* that does it exactly the way I would need it (`/Applications/Utilities/Grapher.app`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I describe in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907045/drawing-formulas-with-quartz-2d/2908269#2908269) to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907045/drawing-formulas-with-quartz-2d), I built a system for doing this in [my iPhone application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/picubed) (which also works on the Mac, but I simply haven't completed that version of the application yet).

I used Core Animation layers to represent the hierarchy of the equation, with Quartz-drawn elements for the various operation types.  This let me animate the typesetting in a relatively lightweight manner, which is smooth on even the first-generation iPhone hardware.

Like with the evaluation of arbitrary equations, splitting the layout into hierarchical layers makes the layout calculations pretty straightforward and flexible.  However, it still took me months to get everything just right.

If you want to use an existing solution, you might look to Matt Gallagher's excellent open source project [Magic Number Machine](http://projectswithlove.com/magicnumbermachine/), which [at least one developer](http://magicnumber.me) has used as the basis for a commercial Mac calculator with equation typesetting.

Comment: Thanks, I already found your answer. I already started working on my own implementation using expression trees. Initially I wanted to use the *mimetex* lib, but unfortunately it is licensed under (cancer-)GPL.

Comment: @Erik - Matt's stuff is licensed BSD-style, so you might look at what he's done first.  Trust me, this sounds simple, but it's time-consuming to get right if you roll your own.

Comment: Yeah. The thing is i need LaTeX-like rendering (preferably almost pixel perfect). Live editability is a huge plus though.

Comment: any chance you'd make yours available? :D

Comment: @Dave - If I can find a way for it to make sense.  It's so tightly integrated with the application, and is its primary hook, that it's difficult to separate the two.  I contributed some of the base layout code to Core Plot when that project was starting, but nothing too specific.  However, enough people have expressed interest that I've speculated about putting together a Kickstarter project to offset the revenue I might lose by opening this up.  It seemed to work well for Glyphish, but that had a broader appeal.

Comment: I'd definitely like to see this code if you can open-source it.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to typeset equations and not build an interactive equation editor, you might want to look at using `troff`. It's got a reasonably simple syntax for equations, outputs postscript, and is part of OS X. The easiest way to use it would also require ghostscript.

As an example (based on the man page):

Create the file file `fib.tr`:

```
.EQ
x sub i = x sub {i-1} + x sub {i-2}
.EN
```

Convert to postscript with `eqn` and `groff`:

```
$ eqn fib.tr | groff -P-b16 > fib.ps
```

Calculate and extract the bounding box with ghostscript:

```
$ gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=bbox -- fib.ps 2> fib.bbox
```

Add the bounding box information to the ps file to generate an eps file:

```
$ cat fib.ps | sed -e '/%%Orientation/rfib.bbox' > fib.eps
```

Convert the eps file to a pdf using a perl script included with most TeX distributions (and available at http://tug.org/epstopdf/)

```
$ epstopdf fib.eps
```

Now you have a pdf image that contains just the rendered equation with minimal padding.

Alternatively, if your users have TeX installed (or you want to go through the hassle of bundling [a minimal TeX distribution](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) with your app), then [LaTeXiT](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php) provides a service to typeset equations and return them as PDF images. You could call it using `NSPerformService`.

Comment: Didn't know about `troff`, sounds promising though. I'll give it a try.

Comment: When i try to render the PS emitted by step 2 (using Preview.app on OSX, or Photoshop) it displays an empty image. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what. That's why I use `epstopdf` - the PDF it generates looks right, whereas if you let Preview.app generate the PDF, it will give you a blank page.