# How to embed Latex in iOS, Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, latex, embed

How to embed Latex in iOS application using Objective C?

Comment: Related: [Rendering mathematical formulas on an iDevice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340478/rendering-mathematical-formulas-on-an-idevice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have no idea what your specific need is, the easiest way is to compile into postscript or PDF and include that. You can also use [Texify](http://www.texify.com/) if your app uses internet connectivity.

If you mean you want to write an app like [TeX Touch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tex-touch/id377627321?mt=8), then you'll have to narrow down the question a bit.