# how to display math equations (integration, algebraic, etc) in UILabel

Tags: math, ios5, equation, ipod-touch

I am working on an app for iPhone and iPod Touch that has to show complex mathematical equations like algebraic, integration, summation formulas along with some text in UILabel.

I researched and found that Latex is the answer, is that correct?
That means I have to work with so many images, created using LaTeX on Mac, on the device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing formulas with Quartz 2d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907045/drawing-formulas-with-quartz-2d)

Comment: See also [Rendering mathematical formulas on an iDevice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340478/rendering-mathematical-formulas-on-an-idevice) and [Rendering Math Formulas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629833/rendering-math-formulas)

Comment: Thanks for the links Brad - I read thru them. So that means the way to display math equations in iOS devices is using Graphics? Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Typesetting of equations will require custom layout beyond what's provided in a standard UILabel. This could be done via direct Quartz drawing, Core Animation layer layout (as I do), or custom view layout. There's no stock way of doing this, short of using something like MathML in a web view.

Comment: Ok. That clarifies a lot. So I think I would need to study more about Quartz right now. Thanks for giving me the correct direction Brad.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post with the solution. Can anyone please validate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t. UILabel is unstyled text. It doesn’t display images or let you position individual elements.